# Are there any REST apis which can be used like Telnet

Tags: rest, api, email, telnet

I am looking for some REST API provider which will allow to send email like how Telnet does. API will accept all parameters like SMTP server, username, password, message etc. and then will send email.

I understand I can do it programmatically using Java or NodeJS. If anyone has used such API please help.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: (Giving your SMTP username and password to joe random API service strikes me as a rather risky plan)

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons email "https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/" can be used to send mail.

Comment: I have not come across any such API which will allow you to  add all parameters including SMTP server.  Having such  API will be security concern but again, provision can be done  to use Auth token instead of credentials. but this will require agreement between many parties.